# Definition of Finite Regular Graph

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, definition

Massey makes the following definition in his book *Singular Homology Theory*:

> A *finite, regular graph* is a pair consisting of a Hausdorff space $X$ and a finite subspace $X^0$ (points of $X^0$ are called *vertices*) such that the following conditions hold:
> (a) $X - X^0$ is the disjoint union of a finite number of open subsets $e_1,\ldots,e_k$, called *edges*. Each $e_i$ is homeomorphic to an open interval of the real line.
> (b) The point set boundary $\bar{e}_i - e_i$ of the edge $e_i$ consists of two distinct vertices, and the pair $(\bar{e}_i,e_i)$ is homeomorphic to the pair $([0,1],(0,1))$.

I feel like it's redundant to require that $X$ be Hausdorff. Doesn't this follow from the rest of the definition?

Comment: If $X = X_0 = \{0,1\}$ with the indiscrete topology then (a) and (b) hold (with $k = 0$). But $X$ is not Hausdorff.